# Bigquery Remote Function: {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': Cloud resource connections not supported in this project}}

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, bigquery-udf

I'm following the [Bigquery Remote Function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions) tutorial but when I try to create `CLOUD_RESOURCE` connection to interact with the Cloud Function by running the following command within the `gcloud` console:
`bq mk --connection --display_name='my_gcf_conn' --connection_type=CLOUD_RESOURCE --project_id=$(gcloud config get-value project) --location=EU  gcf-conn`, It return this error:

`bigquery_client.BigqueryInterfaceError: Error reported by server with missing error fields. Server returned: {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Cloud resource connections not supported in this project.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}`

I created a custom role with `bigquery.connections.delegate` and `bigquery.routines.create` permission and granted on the dataset where I'll create the remote function, I granted permission `cloudfunctions.functions.invoke` (e.g. via Cloud Functions Invoker role) but I couldn't be able to solve this issue to finish this tutorial.

Please, I appreciate any help.

Comment: have you enrolled into this feature's preview?

Comment: It's only in private preview. I asked 2 weeks ago the access, I'm no yet allowed. Be patient...

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I haven't done any kind of enrolled yet. I hadn't read that step in the tutorial before, my bad. Thank you for that one! Also it's seem that after enrroled, we have to wait sitting for a bit.

Comment: Can anybody help me on enrollment? i also want to enrolled for this feature

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant finally I have enabled the RF feature so I could create a connection successfully, but now I'm getting another problem when creating the BigQuery RF. 
The error is this: **Keyword REMOTE is not supported at [2:1]** 
and this below is the Remote Function I'm trying to create:  
```CREATE FUNCTION `my-project-id.my-dataset-name.function-name`(arg_1 INT64, arg_2 STRING) 
RETURNS STRING
REMOTE WITH CONNECTION `my-project-id.us.my-connection`
OPTIONS (endpoint = 'https://us-central1-my-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/my-cloudfunction)
```
I hope to get some help please...